# Android OpenGL Simple Sprite Flicker Issue

Tags: android, opengl-es, sprite

Thank you for your replies.  Below is a java/windows version with no texture just to discount anything with varied Android related issues.  I revised the Move() as suggested and the sprite is still jittery.  It should seem to move silk smooth after all it is only 1 quad - not very compu-intensive.

```
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.media.opengl.GL2;
import javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener;
import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import javax.media.opengl.fixedfunc.GLMatrixFunc;
import javax.media.opengl.glu.GLU;

import com.jogamp.opengl.util.Animator;

public class Practice implements GLEventListener, MouseMotionListener {

    static GLCanvas canvas = new GLCanvas();
    static Animator anim = new Animator(canvas);
    static Frame frame = new Frame();
    private GLU glu;
    private FloatBuffer vertBuff;
    private ByteBuffer indBuff;
    private static float[] color = new float[]{1,1,1,1};
    private static float xpos;
    private static float vel = 100f;
    private static long lastTime = -1;

    @Override
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
        gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        gl.glEnableClientState(GL2.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3,GL2.GL_FLOAT,0,vertBuff);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GLMatrixFunc.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glColor4fv(color,0);
        Move(gl);
        gl.glDrawElements(GL2.GL_TRIANGLES,6,GL2.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,indBuff);

    }

    private void Move(GL2 gl){

        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long timeStep = 0;
        if(lastTime != -1){
            timeStep = time - lastTime;
        }
        if(timeStep < 20){
            try {Thread.sleep(20-timeStep);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
        lastTime = time;

        xpos += vel * timeStep/1000f;
        if(xpos>500){
            xpos = 500;
            vel *= -1;  
        }
        if(xpos<-500){
            xpos = -500;
            vel *= -1;  
        }
        gl.glTranslatef(xpos,0.0f,0.0f);
        gl.glScalef(50.0f,50.0f,1.0f);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();

        gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
        glu = new GLU();

        float[] verts =     {
                                -0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f,
                                0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f,
                                0.5f, 0.5f, -1.0f,
                                -0.5f, 0.5f, -1.0f
                            };
        byte[] inds =       {
                                0,1,3, 1,2,3
                            };

        ByteBuffer  bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(48);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertBuff = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        vertBuff.put(verts);
        vertBuff.position(0);

        indBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(6);
        indBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        indBuff.put(inds);
        indBuff.position(0);

    }

    @Override
    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width,
            int height) {
        GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
        if(height <=0)height=1;
        float aspect = (float)width/height;
        gl.glMatrixMode(GLMatrixFunc.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        float[] ortho = {
                            (float)1/width,0,0,0,
                            0,(float)1/width*aspect,0,0,
                            0,0,1,0,
                            0,0,0,1
                        };
        //gl.glLoadMatrixf(ortho,0);
        glu.gluOrtho2D(-width,width,-height,height);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        float R = (float)1/frame.getWidth()*e.getX();
        float B = (float)1/frame.getHeight()*e.getY();
        color = new float[]{R,.2f,B,1.0f};
    }

    public static void close(){
        anim.stop();
        frame.dispose();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        canvas.addGLEventListener(new Practice());
        canvas.addMouseMotionListener(new Practice());

        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.setSize(500,300);

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
                close();
            };
        });

        frame.setVisible(true);
        anim.start();
        canvas.requestFocus();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find it helpful to draw your sprite always aligned to pixel boundaries, otherwise if it is at random sub-pixel locations the result of the sampling will be different each frame, giving you slightly different appearances for your texture (this could be interpreted as flickering).

The easiest way to do this would be to use gluOrtho to match your viewport width and height (i.e. `gluOrtho2D(0,width,0,height)`, and then only draw the sprites at integer locations. If you want to preserve your '-5 to 5' projection matrix, you'll have to do the math to figure out how to line your sprite texels up exactly with the screen pixels.

Another option may be to try changing from `LINEAR` sampling to `NEAREST` sampling, that might help, but could possibly still flicker occasionally if there is some rounding error in the GPU.

Answer (score 0):

Tried this (Viewpad 10s, VegaComb 3.2); it runs smooth most of the time, but noticably glitches every ~3 seconds. No relationship to GC whatsoever. I moved all static stuff to `onSurfaceCreated` with little to no effect. There is nothing in the code that possibly could explain this behaviour.

The `GLES20TriangleRenderer`(API-Demos) runs more smoothly but glitches, too. Note that this example does considerably more work, yet still nothing that could explain any frametime issues. The `Kube` example (spinning Rubics Cube) *seems* to not glitch, maybe this is a perception issue.

I don't think there's anything that could be done to remedy this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Tested it on HTC Desire S.
Works fine except for occassional glitches.

Still limiting the framerate could make it better.
You can alter your "move" method to something like:

```
long lastTime = -1;
private void Move(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glTranslatef(xpos,0.0f,0.0f);

    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long timeStep = 0;
    if(lastTime != -1){
        timeStep = time - lastTime;
    }
    if(timeStep < 20){
        try {Thread.sleep(20-timeStep);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
    lastTime = time;

    xpos += vel * timeStep/1000.0f;
    if(xpos>5*aspect){
        xpos = 5*aspect;
        vel *= -1;  
    }
    if(xpos<-5*aspect){
        xpos = -5*aspect;
        vel *= -1;  
    }
}
```